# Publishing Kentico CMS 9 - Exception WebFarmTaskManager.CanCreateTask

Tags: kentico

can anyone help me with publishing Kentico CMS 9. When I publish app from visual studio and upload to server I had received this exception:

[image]

When I upload files from developer folder in my computer to same webhosting everything runs well.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in publishing only one from two projects in solution.

From Kentico 9 publish documentation:

> Publishing web application projects
>   If you plan to publish from Visual Studio, we recommend installing Kentico projects with the web site configuration.
>   To use the Publish function of Visual Studio for Kentico web application projects, you need to sequentially publish all of the projects in the solution to the same target location:
>   CMSApp
>   CMSApp_AppCode
>   After deploying the first project, make sure that your publish profile has the Delete all existing files prior to publish / Remove additional files at destination option disabled. You can configure the option in the Publish Web dialog in Settings -> File Publish Options.

[Kentico 9 Documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Publishing+projects+from+Visual+Studio)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug that it isn't built in, Kentico 9 is still new so you may want to log it as a bug.

Otherwise though i believe somewhere in the start up you need to register the farm task indeed by using WebFarmHelper.RegisterTask, perhaps you could try using the Custom Loader Module to add that code there as this runs on start up.

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Handling+global+events

```
using CMS.Base;
using CMS.DocumentEngine;

[CustomDocumentEvents]
public partial class CMSModuleLoader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Attribute class that ensures the loading of custom handlers.
    /// </summary>
    private class CustomDocumentEventsAttribute : CMSLoaderAttribute
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The system executes the Init method of the CMSModuleLoader attributes when the application starts.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Init()
        {
            // Call WebFarmHelper.RegisterTask here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you David Slavik. 
As you said, publish first CMSApp_AppCode, then, in the same folder, CMSApp, but be carefull that the option "Delete all existing files prior to publish" disabled.